# Angular2 how to add ngModel to dynamic component

Tags: angular

Use factory to dynamic add component.

```
   let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.componentFactory);
   (<Component>componentRef.instance).title = title;
   (<Component>componentRef.instance).options = options;
   (<Component>componentRef.instance).value = value;
```

But how can I add `ngModel` attribute to the dynamic component?

Comment: ng model is not a factory, so you are missing the way your form is represented.

Comment: I want to add ngModel to my component like directive. However, dynamic add component in the childNode with ngModel does not work.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use ngModel when creating components manually. However you can use the [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html) approach to wire these manually created components with Angular forms.

Comment: This seems like a huge limitation. One can not dynamically create components that work with forms without using the Reactive forms approach?